# Get current value of RxJava Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

In my UI I have a `RadioGroup` with 3 `RadioButtons` and a "normal" `Button`.

When the user clicks on the `Button` I want to read the selected `RadioButton` to do something with it.

```
RxView.clicks(button)
      .flatMap(x -> RxRadioGroup.checkedChanges(radioGroup_timer))
      .map(view -> {
          switch (view) {
              case R.id.radioButton_10sec_timer:
                  return 10;
              case R.id.radioButton_20sec_timer:
                  return 20;
              default:
                  return DEFAULT_TIMER;
          }
      })
    .subscribe(duration -> Timber.i("duration: %,d",duration));
```

It works so far but now every time the user selects an other `RadioButton` I get a new log message.

Is there a way to read the current selected `RadioButton` without subscribing for changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do smthing like this

```
RxView.clicks(button)
      .withLatestFrom(RxRadioGroup.checkedChanges(radioGroup_timer), (click, checked) -> checked)
      .map(...)
```

**withLatestFrom** will take only LATEST element from the *checkedChanges* stream, and **flatMap** will create new Observable, that will emits ALL items from this stream

Comment: How can I subscribe to all events in a radiogroup for form validation?